# How to make custom spawners in 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The command `/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityID:}` doesn't work anymore in 1.9. What is the alternative now?

Comment: If you have an empty spawner click it with a mob egg and it will start spawning that mob

Comment: I know but you can't do that with iron golem spawners for example.

Comment: Oh.  I see. There is a mod called _TooManyItems_ you could get all spawners from there. I don't know if it's upgraded to 1.9 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EntityId` tag has been removed. Instead, an `id` string inside the `SpawnData` compound specifies the entity ID.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:"Creeper"}}
```

For the `SpawnPotentials` list, the `Properties` compound has been renamed to `Entity`, and the `Type` string tag has been removed in favor of an `id` tag within `Entity`.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnPotentials:[{Weight:1,Entity:{id:"Creeper"}}]}
```